# Does mvc3 razor engine supports output from List.ForEach()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have 2 code block, first:

```
@foreach(var filterName in Model.FilterNames){
    <text>
        $("#@filterName").combobox({
            source:"@(filterName)Autocomplete"
        });
    </text>
}
```

second:

```
@Model.FilterNames.ForEach(filterName => {
    <text>
        $("#@filterName").combobox({
            source:"@(filterName)Autocomplete"
        });
    </text>
})
```

Second one doesn't work. Anyone knows if razor supports this syntax? Or what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Razor does not currently support anonymous methods which is why your second one doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When using a method in razor, it will assume that it is an helper or a property and return either an HelperResult or data.

As the List.ForEach method does return nothing, the call will fail.

Comment: so currently razor doesn't support such syntax ?

Comment: No, it won't find any overload in the `WebPageBase.Write` which take a `void` as argument since it isn't allowed in C#. You'll have to either return the data you want to display or an `HelperResult`.

Comment: It might be possible to use something similar to what you want, but you'll have to use an helper method : look at section "Passing Inline Templates as Parameters" in [http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` is an method on `List<T>` and a usually an extension method people create on `IEnumerable<T>` (so your probably missing the `@using` directive for `System.Collections.Generic` and/or the extension method altogether), but it's considered by many (including [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)) to be poor design from a functional programming perspective.

Stick with your first one.

Or better yet, use an **Editor Template** and save the loop altogether.

Comment: i have System.Collections.Generic included, so that's not it. error is on line `$("#@filterName").combobox({` . error says CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

Comment: @qrow - try wrapping that bit of JS in a `@functions { ... }` block. Is `Model.FilterNames` of type `List<T>`? Still though, i don't agree with using this method here. Just use an editor template, it's the logical and correct thing to do.